# differentiate between two almost identical links in regex

Tags: php, regex, facebook, comments, vbulletin

I have created a plugin that turns links into the Facebook embedded version of the content at the link.  My problem is if I disable the part of the plugin for comments, the links to comments become embedded posts (if the post portion of the plugin is still active).

Lets take a look, so we have 3 links:

Facebook post

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10102577175875681" target="_blank">ONE</a>
```

Comment

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10102577175875681?comment_id=1193531464007751" target="_blank">Two</a>
```

and a reply to a comment

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10102577175875681?comment_id=1193531464007751&reply_comment_id=10102577641662241" target="_blank">Three</a>
```

with all three links beginning with

```
https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10102577175875681
```

In the following code, the if conditions are my setting toggles, and this post message is equal to what a user posts, so in this example this post message is equal to the three links above.

This is the plugin I have created for converting these links.

```
if ($this->registry->options['drcae_facebook_comment_onoff']) {
  // swaps facebook comment links to embed code
  $drc_embed_facebook_cmt = '<div class="fb-comment-embed" data-include-parent="true" data-width="560" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/$3/posts/$4comment_id=$5"></div>';
  $this->post['message'] = preg_replace('~<a (.*)href="(.*)facebook.com/(.*)/posts/(.*)?comment_id=(.*)"(.*)<\/a>~', $drc_embed_facebook_cmt, $this->post['message']);
}

if ($this->registry->options['drcae_facebook_post_onoff']) {
  // swaps facebook post links to embed code
  $drc_embed_facebook_post = '<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/$3/posts/$4"></div>';
  $this->post['message'] = preg_replace('~<a (.*)href="(.*)facebook.com/(.*)/posts/(.*)"(.*)<\/a>~', $drc_embed_facebook_post, $this->post['message']);
}
```

I did have this flipped the other way (post being first) but this caused comments to embed the posts, I got around this by checking for comments first which is probably not the best way to do this.

So you may have noticed my regex, it's not the greatest but it's what I was able to make work on my own being new to regex altogether.

```
~<a (.*)href="(.*)facebook.com/(.*)/posts/(.*)"(.*)<\/a>~
```

I choose to do my regex this way so it didnt matter if a link was formatted like the following it would still embed:

```
<a target="blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/USERNAME/posts/1234567890" alt="facebook post">LINK</a>
```

But now I'm second guessing my work, and after searching and not coming up with anything, I figured I would ask for some assistance.

How can I differentiate between these links so posts, don't interfere with comments / with comment replies?

**Update 1, embeded posts**

Now my plugin looks like this

```
$drc_embed_facebook_post = '<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/$2/posts/$3"></div>';
$this->post['message'] = preg_replace('~<a (.*?)facebook\.com/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([0-9]+)(?:[?][^0-9]+([0-9]+)(?:&(.+))?)?</a>~', $drc_embed_facebook_post, $this->post['message']);
```

Regex specifically

```
~<a (.*?)facebook\.com/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([0-9]+)(?:[?][^0-9]+([0-9]+)(?:&(.+))?)?</a>~
```

I have left the beginning a lazy anything? I believe... to not restrict www. https:// ect... (anything that comes before facebook.com)

This partially works, grabbing links directly to posts here are a few example.

```
https://www.facebook.com/RyanNewMe/posts/616837631826216?pnref=story
https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10102833246942211?pnref=story
https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10102830259184701?pnref=story
```

these links do not embed the post.  However if I remove `?pnref=story` from them all, only the following link does not work.

```
https://www.facebook.com/RyanNewMe/posts/616837631826216
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a nice, fast regex to extract the `href` [earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37259215), so I'm going to use that as a baseline:

```
<a(?:\s*(?!href)[^\s>]*)*\s*href=["']([^"']+)
```

If you use this regex, you will get whatever the value of the `href` attribute is as the match. For example:

```
https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10102577175875681

https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10102577175875681?comment_id=1193531464007751

https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10102577175875681?comment_id=1193531464007751&reply_comment_id=10102577641662241
```

Then you can parse this section.

I made this regex which seems to work:

```
facebook\.com/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([0-9]+)(?:[?][^0-9]+([0-9]+)(?:&(.+))?)?
```

You should find your matches in `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, and `$4` for "zuck", the original id, comment id, and the entire rest of the link respectively. (Yes, I got *lazy* at the end there, do you need the end of the link parsed into pieces?)

It looks really complex, but it's actually pretty understandable.

- `facebook\.com/` matches `facebook.com/`
- `[^\]+` matches one or more non-slashes
- `([0-9]+)` captures one or more numbers
- This blob: `(?:[?][^0-9]+([0-9]+)(?:&(.+))?)?` specifies the optional extensions (that's the ending `?`s).

  - The `(?:)` means non capturing group (mostly to avoid incrementing the names of `$2` and `$3`).
  - `[?][^0-9]+` means that there's a `?` followed by some non digits.
  - `([0-9]+)` captures digits
  - `&(.+)` matches an `&` and then captures the rest of the string.

---

Edit: Regarding your update, the regex can be fixed like this (unless I'm missing the problem):

```
~<a (.*?)facebook\.com/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([0-9]+)(?:[?][^0-9<]+([0-9]*)(?:&([^<]+))?)?</a>~
```

Comment: Making me stack questions here but HOW! lol, I understand what it does, but how in the world do you guys come up with the proper regex's I've tried gens, tuts, and posts after posts, I cant come up with a regex to save my life lol, just grew fond of using ANYTHING `(.*)` lol.   but if i undersatnd this properly I can ditch the whole `~<a (.*)href="(.*)facebook.com/(.*)/posts/(.*)"(.*)<\/a>~`  and use... `preg_replace('~<a (.*)href="facebook\.com/[^/]+/[^/]+/([0-9]+)(?:[?][^0-9]+([0-9]+)(?:&(.+))?)? (.*)<\/a>~'`

Comment: and something feels off, this bit `facebook\.com/[^/]+/[^/]+/([0-9]+)` should contain $1 and $2 we need to change zuck and the post number

Comment: @DrCustUmz The end of that should be `(?:&(.+))?)?</a>~`, and the start could be lazy like: `<a (.*?)`. You can use https://regex101.com/# to test things. I also just updated my answer with the new capture group.

Comment: this part though `facebook\.com/[^/]+/[^/]+/([0-9]+)` changing it to `facebook\.com/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([0-9]+)` would work correct?  oops saw your edit =) and I did have it... slowly catching, oh wait, a flower ;P

Will give it a run and be right back, THANK YOU!

Comment: I have updated the OP, I have not got to testing embeded comments yet.

Comment: Im playing around with the link you gave me, I think I'm closer but having trouble with the numbers part `~<a(.*?)facebook\.com/(.*)/posts/([0-9]+)(?:[?][^0-9]+([0-9]+)(?:&(.+))?)?</a>~` note* I went with (.*) for $2 not only because its what I know, but because a username on FB can be anything can't it?

Comment: @DrCustUmz I can't find anything definitive, but you're not supposed to have that much freedom with a username. It certainly shouldn't contain a `/` in any case.